# what is EEAP build?

Tags: build, windows-8

I read about [Microsoft Windows 8](http://www.winextra.com/tech/software/microsoft-setting-traps-for-leakers-with-newest-tester-build-of-windows-8/) builds.

What is an EEAP build? What does the abbreviation EEAP stand for?

Comment: Something like Enterprise Early Access Program (not too sure about the first E).

Comment: But this is not a programming question, so vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a "MS signed version" in opposition to non signed for internal test, something like that...

Answer (score 1):

Ecosystem Engagement Access Program: high frequency (weekly?) OS releases made to NDA partners (OEM, IHV, ISV)